# И снова History API

Tags: javascript, history-api

Доброго времени суток. Я понимаю, что вопросы и ответы на тему History API уже тут были, но они мне не помогли, поэтому прошу помощи ещё раз.
Всё в роде бы работает, кроме кнопки "назад". Когда нажимаю в браузере на кнопку "назад", то url меняется на нужный, но данные не обновляются.

Вот код:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for( var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++ ) {
    anchors[i].onclick = loader;
  }

  function loader() {
    var state = {
      title: this.getAttribute("title"),
      url: this.getAttribute("href", 2)
    };
    history.pushState(state, state.title, state.url);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: state.url,
      data: { data: 'text' },
      success: function(html) {
        $('#content').html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

}

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log('onpopstate event was fired');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: event.url,
    data: { data: 'text' },
    success: function(html) {
      history.replaceState(event, event.title, event.url);
      $('#content').html(html);
    }
  });
};
```

Прошу помощи в данном вопросе.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но примерно тоже самое написано и на многих других источниках. Вы можете сказать в чём проблема именно в моём коде?

Comment: @LightShock сорри, ответил по утру, не особо вникая в код. Сообщение-то в и вроде удалил, но почему-то осталось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте преобразовать в строку в этой части:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: (event.url).toString(),
    /* ... */
```

А вообще, я бы даже так сделал:

```
$( window ).on( 'popstate', function( e ) {
    var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;
    var backUri = returnLocation.toString();
    // тут подгружаем данные по истории вперед/назад
    $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
});
```

P.S. Последнее, на что обратил внимание, так это в общем у вас код на pure JS, а ajax-запрос на jQuery. Поэтому, на всякий случай - а библиотеку jQuery подключили?

Comment: @Deonis, конечно подключил, иначе у меня проблемы с ajax бы были) Спасибо за код, понял в чём проблема была)